# gspread get key once opened by title

Tags: python, gspread

how do I get the key of the workbook if I know only the name of the workbook? I can use open by title, but once i'm in I didn't find a `get.key` type method in the documents. Is there a way to get the key by only knowing the title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access a spreadsheet key with `mySpreadSheet.id` after you have opened it by title.